# Symfony 2 retrieving date fields using Doctrine 2

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've a table called 'PatientIdentification_tbl'. I am trying to  retrieve some columns and output in json format.

But in the output, the value for the  'datetime' or 'date' column types doesn't output the entered date or datetime, but show this,

```
"dateofbirth":{"lastErrors":{"warning_count":0,"warnings":[],"error_count":0,"errors":[]},"timezone":{"name":"Europe\/Berlin","location":{"country_code":"DE","latitude":52.5,"longitude":13.36666,"comments":"most locations"}},"offset":3600,"timestamp":-91760400}
```

Can someone help me find the issue here, so that the date is retrieved properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want maybe:

```
$dateofbirth->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Comment: Perfect! This what the getter looks like now.     /**
     * Get dateofbirth
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateofbirth()
    {
        return $this->dateofbirth->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }